# Brushes thread safety

Tags: winforms, brushes

According to the usual Thread safety statement.

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe

Which makes `Brushes.White` thread safe but not `new SolidBrush(Color.White)`

My first question is why, what are the technical differences in the back?

Second, can threadsafe simple brushes such as Brushes.White be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is boilerplate verbiage for 99.9% of all .NET classes.  Pretty useless.  A brush has an internal *immutable* field, it is checked when you set the brush's Color property.  Doesn't have anything to do with threading, it just prevents you from changing the color of a stock brush (like Brushes.White).  Which would of course be pretty bad.  With no other property left to modify, that makes a stock brush thread-safe by coincidence.

Odds are fairly decent that your own SolidBrush is thread-safe too, GDI+ has some internal locking built-in.  You can for example have multiple threads draw to a bitmap, as long as they are different bitmaps.  It is however not explicitly documented to be thread-safe so you'd do this at your own risk.  Which is fairly pointless to exercise, it just doesn't make much sense to change the color of a brush after creating it.  Or for that matter to have multiple threads use the same brush.  A brush is very cheap, it takes only a microsecond to create one.